# GNU utility: sort 

Tags: sort

I have an issue sorting a file based on the first two columns.

The layout of the file is:

```
1 998688068 PizzaFan Insurance 22.47
5 072821325 Plaisio Computers 26.35
4 998688068 PizzaFan Food 27.32
5 456834578 G.Yannopoulos Medical 91.67
```

....
....

I used this command :
`sort -n -k 1,2 "$fpath" -o "$fpath.ordered"`

The sort result is:

```
1 473151252 Goodys Food 7.15
1 951515524 Atlantic SuperMarket 41.32
1 998688068 Atlantic SuperMarket 80.23
1 998688068 PizzaFan Food 61.72
1 998688068 PizzaFan Insurance 22.47
2 094321587 Vasilopoulos SuperMarket 6.50
```

....
....

I don't understand why all columns get sorted (see 3rd column & PizzaFan Insurance)

I think -k 1,2 means sort on column 1 and resolve ties with column 2, but it's like it doesn't work.

It's the same as using the:
`sort -n "$fpath" -o "$fpath.ordered"`

Comment: kalispera file :) Goodys gia panta :P

Comment: I don't understand why `sort` made entries appear and disappear. Can you post the whole file or show a shorter example?

Comment: It is just a portion of the file entries don't dissappear they are just sorted, but I didn't post the whole file

Answer (score 5):

If you want a stable sort (relative order of the input rows is preserved in case of ties), you need to use the `-s` or `--stable` flag.

Answer (score 4):

If you want GNU sort to be [**stable**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) then you must pass `-s`. Otherwise, records with the same key will come out in an arbitrary order based on `sort`'s internal algorithm.